# ng lint - TypeError: context.hasher.hashTask is not a function

Tags: nestjs, angular-cli, eslint, nrwl-nx, nrwl

I just wanted to add linting to my project. Here is what it did:

> nx g @nrwl/angular:application fuzzy

And then tried to lint it

```
> ng lint
Unexpected error:
TypeError: context.hasher.hashTask is not a function
    at A:\web-app\node_modules\@nrwl\linter\src\executors\eslint\hasher.js:6:42
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at A:\web-app\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Object.__awaiter (A:\web-app\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:114:16)
    at run (A:\web-app\node_modules\@nrwl\linter\src\executors\eslint\hasher.js:5:20)
    at TasksSchedule.<anonymous> (A:\web-app\node_modules\nx\src\tasks-runner\tasks-schedule.js:117:19)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at A:\web-app\node_modules\tslib\tslib.js:118:75
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
```

I use a NX Monorepo with Angular 13 and NestJS.

The documentation about the context.hasher? is also not helpful.

My workspace is about 3 years old and something about nx is broken in my workspace, but as i have currently no clue, why this error occurs, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Finally i have found the solution!
Turns out the project still uses TSlint, which is deprecated. Migrating to ESlint fixed the issue.

> nx generate convert-tslint-to-eslint web-app

https://nx.dev/packages/angular/generators/convert-tslint-to-eslint

Comment: I had the same error. I updated all my nx dependencies `npx nx migrate latest` then I ran the migrations `npx nx migrate --run-migrations `.